# Laravel, jquery Interdependent select lists Full code

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have got it all fine until the last line of code where I cannot load it into the Select list of the View. I can't get the second select list populated (countries regions cities), but I am knackered because it all seems very clear to me and I dont understand why it can't. In firebug I am able (at the HTML tab) to load the select list of regions alright, but can't send it to the View. You might think that it would be just a matter of sending the array to the view from the controller, but that won't work because it will complain with a `variable undefined` at the View. So you cant have any variable there waiting for any value if that was pregenerated in an ajax fashion, so I can generate it at the controller (or in the model too) but it is only viewable in Firebug. I would enormously appreciate because I have gone to the limit of my ability. I had it working in Codeigniter, but cant reproduce it in Laravel. Here is the stuff:

THE JQUERY CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

      //When the first select list changes, then the function activates itself

       $('#country').change(cargarProvincias); //load regions when countries change

    });

    function cargarProvincias() {

        // collects the selected value

       var id_pais = $('#country').val();

        // sends the parameter to the controller. It is definitively a correct url as I can see the result
        $regionsurl = '{{URL::route('getregionslist')}}';

//I tried also with $.post, same results as with get. Had to change the route accordingly, of course.

        $.get( $regionsurl, {'id_pais':id_pais} ) ,function(resp){

            //then the controller gets that value and sends it to the Model
            // and the Model does retrieve the correct result.
            // I put that result into a string and that should be picked up by the
            // html function here below (inside the resp parameter) and fill up the select lists at the View

        $('#regions').empty().html(resp);

        };

        }



     </script>
```

HERE IS THE CONTROLLER:

```
public function getregionslist(){

        $id_pais = Input::get('id_pais');               
        (new region)->getregion($id_pais);

    }

It does get the correct id from the View and also gets (if I try it, the correct feedback from the Model)

HERE IS THE MODEL (it does get correct results) but it does not get echoed at the View


 public function getregion($id_pais) {


        $regions = DB::table('regions')->where('id_pais', $id_pais)->get();

         $cadena = ""; 
         foreach ($regions as $region){
         $cadena .= "<option value ='$region->id_region'>$region->nombre_region</option>";          
       }

        echo $cadena;

        return $cadena;

    }
```

If for example I look in Firebug what cadena brings for Canada, it will bring this, which is correct:

```
<option value ='2055'>Alberta</option><option value ='2056'>British Columbia</option><option value ='2053'>Manitoba</option><option value ='2050'>New Brunswick</option><option value ='2047'>Newfoundland</option><option value ='2058'>Northwest Territories</option><option value ='2048'>Nova Scotia</option><option value ='2057'>Nunavut</option><option value ='2052'>Ontario</option><option value ='2049'>Prince Edward Island</option><option value ='2051'>Quebec</option><option value ='2054'>Saskatchewan</option><option value ='2059'>Yukon Territory</option>
```

AND THE VIEW IS:

Private land

```
    <select name ="regions" id ="regions" class="form-control">

            </select>
```

Yes, we would have wished we could have just sent the array from the controller and then do a `@foreach $regions ->$region` at the View, but that will fail miserably because it will always return `variable $regions" undefined`, so I have to do it at the model (or the controller) and not have any variable waiting for values at the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using following code:

```
$id_pais = Input::get('id_pais');               
(new region)->getregion($id_pais);
```

Use following code in your controller:

```
$region = Region::whereId(Input::get('id_pais'))->lists('id_region', 'nombre_region');
return Response::json($region);
```

Then in the client side use `jQuery` to build the dropdown/select, like this:

```
$.getJSON($regionsurl, {'id_pais':id_pais}, function(resp) {
    $('#regions').empty();
    $.each(resp, function(key, value){
        var option = $('<option/>', {'id':key, 'text':value});
        $('#regions').append(option);
    });
});
```

Also make sure you declare the `Region` class/model like this:

```
class Region Extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'regions';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_pais'; // if id_pais is your primary key
    // code...
}
```

P/S: You need to learn/read more from [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs).

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution,I voted it positively. Aside from that, I found out the reason of the issue. It was a single parentheses wrongly placed at the jquery function. This parentheses to the left of the word "function" was the culprit id_pais':id_pais} ) ,function

Comment: Glad you made it, +1 :-)

Comment: yes it took me about 24 hours, but your solution is very intersting and I learned from it.

Comment: Also `getJson` should be `getJSON`, it was a typo.